# Getting hold of Kafka Stream in process() method

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I'm working on a POC to demonstrate some Spring Cloud Kafka capabilities.  I am using Java 11 with SpringBoot 2.4.1.  My build.gradle has the following libraries

```
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

I have created a SpringBoot component as shown below

```
public class FirstConsumer implements Processor<String, AirSupportRequest> {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirstConsumer.class);
    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, LocationSupport value) {
        logger.info("Key : " + key + value.toString());
        Predicate<String, LocationSupport> northAmerica = (k, v) -> v.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("NORTHAMERICA");
        Predicate<String, LocationSupport> asia = (k, v) -> v.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("ASIA");

        KStream<String, LocationSupport>[] branches = <How do I get reference to the stream instantiated by Spring Cloud Stream>
```

My application.yml has the following code

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            functions:
              process:
                applicationId: asr
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          destination: location_stream
```

Based on my configuration Spring Cloud has instantiated a stream already.  My question is how do I reference that stream in my code to filter and create branches of streams.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown above as the processor is the implementation of the low-level processor API in Kafka Streams. The way you establish a binding using the Kafka Streams binder is by providing a functional bean. For instance,

```
@Bean
public Consumer<KStream<String, AirSupportRequest>> proess() {

  return ks -> {}
}
```

Then `process-in-0.destination` consumes from the Kafka topic and hand the data over to the consumer.

You can mix and match the processor API with the DSL approach. See [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_mixing_high_level_dsl_and_low_level_processor_api) from the docs.

Here is some info for [branching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_multiple_output_bindings) in Kafka Streams in particular when it comes to using it in Spring Cloud Stream.

Comment: Reference for mixing high level DSL with low level API was helpful.  I missed that part before.